# Division of complex numbers with formula

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the problem given below by using a formula given in my reference book

The question is...

*Find real values of x and y for which following equation is satisfied:*

$$\frac{x-1}{3+i}+\frac{y-1}{3-1}=i$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

When i use the division formula for complex numbers i.e.:

$$\frac{(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)+i(x_2y_1-x_1y_2)}{x_2^2+y_2^2}$$

Where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are real parts of given complex numbers and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are imaginary parts of given complex numbers.

So when I use the above formula to simplify and reduce the given equation to standard form i.e.:

$$X + iY$$

I get the wrong answer, while when I don't use the formula and manually solve the question stepwise I get right answer.

My question is that why this formula is not working in this case while it works in all other cases???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for formatting tips.

Comment: We can't comment on what is going wrong if you don't show your work.

Comment: Is the denominator of the second fraction really supposed to be $3-1,$ or is that a typo for $3-i?$